# Intuitive difference between two probability events for random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have two probability statements for a given random variable $x(t)$ being inside a set $C$ for time $t \in T$.

1. $\mathbb{P}(x(t) \in C, \ \ \forall t \in T) \leq 0.5 $
2. $\mathbb{P}(x(t) \in C) \leq 0.5$, for all time $t \in T$.

Notice that in the second statement, the time variable appears outside the probability.

I know that the first statement means that the probability of $x$ remaining inside the set $C$ for all time $t \in T$ is less than 0.5. Which also means that with a probability of at least 0.5, $x$ may jump out of the set $C$.

I am confused with the second statement though. I feel like the second statement essentially means that at each time $t$, the probability of being in set $C$ is less than 0.5. So for all time $t$, it would essentially be a multiplication of the probability for all $t \in T$, and therefore the probability of being in set $C$ for all time $t$ becomes 0. Am I correct in this or is there something I'm missing?

I'd appreciate a proper difference between the two statements, perhaps in an intuitive manner.

A follow up to this question:

What if the probability of both events in $1$ and $2$ are equal to $1$? Then, would there be any difference between the two?

Comment: Well for (2), you're assuming that the probability at different points is independent. Which is fine, but to be noted. And even then it would be $\leq (0.5)^{|T|}$ so you get $0$ only if $T$ is an infinite stretch of time. Also true I suppose if your 'resolution' on $T$ is infinite (i.e, $t$ accounts for every second and microsecond and femtosecond and... so till infinitely small units) then yes, the probability does limit to $0$.

Comment: @Vercingetorix thank you for your comment. It makes sense. Could you also let me know if the two statements become equivalent if both probabilities are 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For any $t\in T$ it is always true that
  $$\tag{1}
  \mathbb{P}\Big\{x(s) \in C, \ \ \forall s \in T\Big\} \leq \mathbb{P}\Big\{x(t) \in C\Big\}\,
  $$
  simply because the set on the LHS is a subset of the set on the RHS.
- Obviously: when the LHS is one then the RHS is one. The converse is however not true.
- When the $x(t)$ are all indedpendent then, for each countable subset $N$ of $T$ we have
  $$\tag{2}
  \mathbb{P}\Big\{x(s) \in C, \ \ \forall s \in N\Big\}=\prod_{s\in N}  \mathbb{P}\Big\{x(s) \in C\Big\}\,.
  $$
- Therefore (assuming independence), when $\mathbb{P}\{x(s) \in C\}=1$ for every $s\in N$ the LHS of (2) is one. (We can however not conclude that the LHS of (1) is one because that is only a subset.)
- When the $x(t)$ are i.i.d. then (2) becomes
  $$\tag{3}
  \mathbb{P}\Big\{x(s) \in C, \ \ \forall s \in N\Big\}=\Big(\mathbb{P}\Big\{x(0) \in C\Big\}\Big)^{|N|}\,.
  $$
  When $\mathbb{P}\{x(0) \in C\}<1$ we can make both sides of (3) arbitrarily small by choosing $|N|$ sufficiently large. This also makes the LHS of (1) arbitrarily small.
  In particular we have under the i.i.d assumption
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\Big\{x(0) \in C\Big\}\in[0,1)\quad\Rightarrow\quad\mathbb{P}\Big\{x(s) \in C\quad\forall s\in T\Big\}=0\,.
  $$
- A typical situation when both statements become equivalent occurs in the theory of stochastic processes with continuous sample paths $t\mapsto x(t)$. There the idea to prove
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\Big\{x(s) \in C\Big\}=1\,,\forall s\in T\quad\Rightarrow\quad\mathbb{P}\Big\{x(s) \in C\quad\forall s\in T\Big\}=1
  $$
  is to realize that it is enough to prove this for a countable dense subset of $T$.

Comment: Thank you! This is the exact explanation I was looking for!